# how to loop through in React JSX and build multiple <td> based on condition

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I need to divide data in JSON in multiple columns. I have the column header length as variable: colspanL1 . In the JSON I am getting an array which

1. sometime gets data for all the columns
2. Sometime gets data for some columns and for others get N/A
3. sometime gets data just for some columns

The below code is able to handle first 2 conditions. For last condition I want to run a for loop for the below piece `<td> {data === "N/A" ? "" : getFormattedValue(data, true)} </td>` I want this section to be inside FOR loop which will run for the missing data. This FOR loop should run based on condition:

(cellLen -1 === index && cellLen !== colspanL1 )

where cellLen is the length of the Array and index is index of items inside array. That means when (cellLen -1)= Index (end of the array) but cellLen is not equal to the number of columns. At that time the FOR loop should run to have those many empty cells i.e. "`<td>`" tag. Below is the TBODY code where I want to introduce this FOR logic

```html
<tbody>
  {Object.entries(formattedData.rowsData).map( ([key, rowData], index) => { return ( rowData && Array.isArray(rowData) && (
  <tr>
    {rowData.map((cellData, index) => { return index === 0 ? (
    <td>{cellData}</td>
    ) : ( cellData.map((data, index) => { return typeof data === "string" && data.includes("%") ? (
    <td className={`${ parseFloat(data)> 0 ? "color-green" : "color-red" }`} > {data}
    </td>
    ) : (
    <td>
      {data === "N/A" ? "" : getFormattedValue(data, true)}
    </td>
    ); }) ); })}
  </tr>
  ) ); } )}
</tbody>
```

I need to get something like this:

```html
<tbody>
      {Object.entries(formattedData.rowsData).map( ([key, rowData], index) => { return ( rowData && Array.isArray(rowData) && (
      <tr>
        {rowData.map((cellData, index) => { return index === 0 ? (
        <td>{cellData}</td>
        ) : ( cellData.map((data, index) => { return typeof data === "string" && data.includes("%") ? (
        <td className={`${ parseFloat(data)> 0 ? "color-green" : "color-red" }`} > {data}
        </td>
        ) : ///this is the code change I am looking for.IF condition satisfied run FOR to create TD
        IF (cellLen -1 === index && cellLen !== colspanL1 ) then for(i=0;i<=colspanL1 - cellLen;i++)
              (
              <td>
                {data === "N/A" ? "" : getFormattedValue(data, true)}
              </td>
        ); }) ); })}
      </tr>
      ) ); } )}
    </tbody>
```